# How to train a single Artificial Neuron to predict f(x), where f(x)=x

Tags: neural-network

Conditions :

```
1. Network architecture: one single neuron.
2. x=99 (real number)
3. input to the neuron is x, output must be f(x) after trained.
4. use one bias and one weight.
5. use MSE for calculating error.
6. use gradient descent(original version) for back propagation.
7. learning rate: 0.01, no decay, no momentum.
8. must assign random value of weight and bias
```

will it work for this problem?

Comment: are you familiar with linear regression?

Comment: yes. yes. yes. yes (sorry, "comment must be 15 chars length")

Comment: Could you expand for condition number 2? I am not familiar with that notation, but *think* it means "99 in base 10". Are you saying that the input $x$ will always take the value 99.0? In which case your network is expected to learn to represent $f(x) = x$ from just one example? Or is this some other constraint, and I have misunderstood the notation?

Comment: @NeilSlater yes, 99 is in decimal and input x will always take the value 99 and this single artificial  neuron  must learn f(99)=99 from just one example.

Comment: Thanks. One more question - which definition of MSE loss are you using? It could be $\mathcal{L}(y, \hat{y}) = (y - \hat{y})^2$ or $\mathcal{L}(y, \hat{y}) = \frac{1}{2}(y - \hat{y})^2$, and actually this difference could be important in your case.

Comment: @NeilSlater the first one.

Comment: @NeilSlater I found it, the problem is learning rate. it will work with learning rate 0.0001. the gradient of w and b will be a huge number, so multiplying it with 0.01 will overshoot the solution. I found this in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752623/training-a-single-linear-neuron-for-regression-using-batch-gradient-descent] stackoverflow. thanks for trying to help me. should I have to delete this question now?

Comment: @bipulkalita: That is up to you. I was assuming that this was a set problem for showing you the importance of learning rate, because the values seem very specific to cause divergence (although if you set this up yourself, you have just been unlucky in your choices). As well as the learning rate issue here, you should expect to not converge on the general $f(x) = x$ line, because one point is not enough information to fit a line uniquely.

Comment: @NeilSlater No, this was not set, why should  i set this up? I was just playing with one neuron then this happened, I tried learning rate to 0.001 still did not help, then I thought what could be the problem here, that's why I posted in this community. also I said x =99

Comment: The values and deliberate simplification of the problem looked like a typical textbook or course problem, that is all. One thing you could do, rather than delete the question, is answer it yourself, showing your bad then improved results. Self-answering is encouraged on this site, because the goal is not just helping people, but storing questions and answers for people to find later (maybe via a web search).

Answer (score 0):

This will not work.

because, for this problem x=99, and when finding gradients, the results will be large numbers and updating weight and bias using learning rate 0.01 will take huge steps, and so the bias and weight will cross the solutions.

using learning rate less than 0.001 will solve this problem.

I tried learning rate 0.0001 and it worked.